# How Visual Studio Intellisense works?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Can somebody please shed light on how exactly intellisense works in Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you looking for how to use it efficiently or details on how it is implemented?

Comment: How it is implemented? Just to know .... :-) because as soon as i make change somewhere its reflected in the intellisense, that's just amazing.

Comment: I think you want details on how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) providing an overview.  It discusses features, language specific topics, customation, when it's not available and a number of other topics.

Answer (score 5):

The secret behind intellisense is Build Providers, which run in the background. This article will throw more light on this topic:

http://aspalliance.com/1102_Creating_a_Custom_BuildProvider_in_ASPNET_20

Hope this helps,